# What changes need to do for my Java Code to execute .bat and get output

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch Output from .bat file running from java.
I am getting only first line and rest all empty.

my Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Test4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String lineInner = null;
    try {
        String line = null;
        String cmd = "F:\\Softwares\\Pega\\117090_Pega8.62_StudioFile\\scripts\\migrate.bat";
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = r.exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
            lineInner = s;
            lineInner = line + "\n" + lineInner;
        }

    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

**Output:**

Invoke our ant script, passing in the arguments as collected

---

**While running directly .bat file I am getting long response as below.**

Invoke our ant script, passing in the arguments as collected
Buildfile: F:\Softwares\Pega\117090_Pega8.62_StudioFile\scripts\migrateSystem.xml

CollectProperties:
[pega:propertyparser] Reading Properties from: F:\Softwares\Pega\117090_Pega8.62_StudioFile\scripts/migrateSystem.properties
[echo] Using logging configuration from: F:\Softwares\Pega\117090_Pega8.62_StudioFile\scripts/config/deploylogging.properties
[echo] *** JVM Arguments -Xmx4g  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -Djava.util.logging.config.file='F:\Softwares\Pega\117090_Pega8.62_StudioFile\scripts/config/deploylogging.properties' ***
[mkdir] Created dir: F:\Pega\temp\MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53
[echo] Using temporary directory F:/Pega/temp/MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53

VerifyProperties:
[echo] Perform pre-upgrade tasks: true
[echo] Perform data schema tables movement: false
[pega:getdataadminsystemsetting] No DASS setting found in database with Owning ruleset 'Pega-Engine' and Setting Purpose 'ZeroDowntimeUpgradeInProgress'

Setup:

Generate Table Lists:
[echo] SchemaAssignmentUtility methods: move,movetorules
[echo] SchemaAssignmentUtility output files: F:/Pega/temp/MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53/tables.txt,F:/Pega/temp/MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53/datatorulestables.txt
[java] Platform = postgres
[java] skipTruncates value =
[java] moveCompelteSchema value = null
[java] Filename:F:/Pega/temp/MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53/tables.txt,F:/Pega/temp/MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53/datatorulestables.txt
[java] Executing method 'GET_MOVE' -- writing output to 'F:/Pega/temp/MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53/tables.txt'
[java] Executing method 'GET_MOVE_TO_RULES' -- writing output to 'F:/Pega/temp/MigrateTemp-16-February-2022-18.09.53/datatorulestables.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your OS is MS Windows. You have to prefix your command with "`cmd /c` ", so Windows knows which command processor to use.